# ggplot Converted into ggplotly Not Displayed all charts in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I have 3 plots in dropdown, using ggplotly [convert from ggplot] "bar", "area", "histogram". based on the selection, the respective chart will be display in the "rfp" plotly area [at a time, i am selecting only one plot]. but the problem i am facing is, i am not able to see first two charts "bar", "area" based on the selection. only third chart i am able to view as part of plotly area based on the selection. [but while i use ggplot, i  didn't face this issue]

ui.r

`tabPanel('Charts', plotlyOutput("rfp"))`

server.r

```
output$rfp <- renderPlotly({


if ((input$ChartType=="Bar" )){
        SimBar <-ggplot(dataset, aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(dataset[,prd])), y=..count..)) +
        geom_bar(stat="count")
        print(ggplotly(SimBar))}

if ((input$ChartType=="Area" ){
        Area <- ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x=dataset[,prd]))+
        geom_density(stat = "bin", alpha=0.5)
        print(ggplotly(Area))}

if ((input$ChartType=="Histogram" ){
        Hist <- ggplot(dataset, aes((x=dataset[,prd])))+
        geom_histogram (stat = "count")
        print(ggplotly(Hist))}
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any "`renderXXX`" works like a function: it returns the result of the last statement of its body. Here your last statement is `if(input$ChartType=="Histogram"){ ... }`. This is `NULL` if `input$ChartType` is not `"Histogram"`. You can do as follows:

```
output$rfp <- renderPlotly({
  if(input$ChartType=="Bar"){
    gg <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(dataset[,prd])), y=..count..)) +
      geom_bar(stat="count")
  }else if(input$ChartType=="Area"){
    gg <- ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x=dataset[,prd])) +
      geom_density(stat = "bin", alpha=0.5)
  }else if(input$ChartType=="Histogram"){
    gg <- ggplot(dataset, aes((x=dataset[,prd]))) +
      geom_histogram(stat = "count")
  }
  ggplotly(gg)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. But i don't know, why i didn't face this issue while i use chart output as **ggplot**